# Sacar elementos de una sublista

Tags: python, array

Este es el problema:
Escribir una función que aplane los arreglos en un nivel, o sea, sacar el contenido de un subarreglo (dentro de otro arreglo) y ponerlos todos al mismo nivel.

Tengo este arreglo:

```
array = ["Palabra", 22, True, [12, 54, "Hola"], [None, False, [1,0]]]
```

Trato de sacar los elementos dentro de las sublistas; pero, o me da error, o simplemente pasa de largo y saca todos los elementos tal como están, con sublistas incluidas.
Quiero que este sea el resultado cuando lo imprima:

```
["Palabra", 22, True, 12, 54, "Hola", None, False, [1,0]]
```

Comment: Haz intentado algo? Podtiasnñadir el código de la que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido efectivamente el resultado que buscaba. Aunque me gustaria saber si alguien propone una solucion q saque todos los elementos de sus sublistas, incluyendo a [1,0]. Aqui está mi solucion:

```
array = ["Palabra", 22, True, [12, 54, "Hola"], [None, False, [1,0]]]

lista = []
centinela = False

for i in array:
    centinela = isinstance(i, list)
    j=0
    if centinela == True:
        for j in i:
            lista.append(j)
    
    else:
        lista.append(i)

print(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo se puede mejorar en varios aspectos

```
array1 = ["Palabra", 22, True, [12, 54, "Hola"], [None, False, [1,0]]]
#se declara un nuevo arreglo
array2 =[]

#recorremos el arreglo 
for e in range(len(array1)):  
     #verificamos el tipo de dato
     if type(array1[e]) is list:          
         for i in array1[e]:
                array2.append(i)
     else:
          array2.append(array1[e])
print(array2)
```

Y para hacer que saque todos los arreglos podemos hacer una función recursiva.

**función recursiva**

```
l2 =[]
#hacemos lo mismo del código anterior
def sacar(lista,lista2):
     for l1 in range(len(lista)):
          if type(lista[l1]) is list:
               #aqyi la recursividad 
               sacar(lista[l1],l2)
          else:
               lista2.append(lista[l1])

arr =["Palabra", 22, True, [12, 54, "Hola"], [None, False, [1,0]]]
```

**Probamos**

```
sacar(arr,l2)
print(l2)
```

**Nota**
No es recomendable para arreglos muy grandes, esto por la recursividad.

Answer (score 0):

Esta versión sin recursividad y puede *flatear* cualquier arreglo de sublistas.

El truco está en verificar si el primer elemento es lista (`if`). Si es así, entonces se expande solo ese elemento, se agrega al resto de elementos y se sobre-escribe la lista original con esa nueva lista. El concepto:

```
>>> x = [[1, 2], 3, 4, [5, [6, 7]]]
>>> x[0] + x[1:]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, [6, 7]]] # Se eliminó un nivel de la primera lista
```

Si no es lista (`else`), [pop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) elimina y retorna el primer valor del array el cual es asignado a un generador ([yield](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)). Luego se repite todo el proceso para la lista resultante. El código:

```
def flat_array(array):
    while array: # Mientras array sea distinto de []
        if isinstance(array[0], list):  # Si el primer elemento es lista
            array = array[0] + array[1:]  # Reduce un nivel de la lista array[0]
        else:
            yield array.pop(0)  # Se agrega a un generador y se remueve de la lista
```

Probando:

```
array1 = ["Palabra", 22, True, [12, 54, "Hola"], [None, False, [1,0]]]
res = flat_array(array1)
print(list(res)) # -> ['Palabra', 22, True, 12, 54, 'Hola', None, False, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una solución usando un generador:

```
def pull(obj, max_level=1, level=1):
  for e in obj:
    if isinstance(e, list) and level <= max_level:
      yield from pull(e, max_level, level + 1)
    else:
      yield e

# max_level = 1
lista = list(pull(array, max_level=1))
print(lista)
['Palabra', 22, True, 12, 54, 'Hola', None, False, [1, 0]]

# max_level = 2
lista = list(pull(array, max_level=2))
print(lista)
['Palabra', 22, True, 12, 54, 'Hola', None, False, 1, 0]
```

`pull()` es una función recursiva que va extrayendo elementos de una lista anidada hasta un `max_level`. Básicamente se recorre la lista, y cuando un elemento es otra lista y nos encontremos en un nivel menor o igual a `max_level`, volvemos a invocar (recursivamente) a `pull()` y así hasta el final de la lista.

**Importante**: El nivel de recursión es finito, y se puede consultar `import sys;print(sys.getrecursionlimit())`